# USB 2.0 ports not working 14.04 device descriptor read/64, error -32

Tags: usb, usb-drive

Tried asking this on ubuntuforums but nothing forthcoming there. Here's my issue:

Hello I wonder if someone can help me with this. I have searched but yet to find an answer that works.

Ubuntu 14.04 fresh install on a custom built PC using a Gigabyte 990XA-UD3 motherboard. The BIOS was updated to the latest version using Q-flash and I chose to load the defaults (where it said everything would work).

USB 3.0 ports work, USB 2.0 ports do not and there are 8 xUSD 2.0 ports and 3x USB 3.0 ports.
Physically for example I plug in the USB mouse I am using into a USB 2.0 port, the laser light flashes, then goes off.
The mouse fails to work, as does any other USB device plugged into the USB 2.0 ports.

lsusb brings

```
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 011 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 010 Device 006: ID 192f:0916 Avago Technologies, Pte. 
Bus 010 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 003: ID 0bda:8178 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8192CU 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 1a2c:0e24 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd 
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

when I run dmesg I see (at the end)

```
[ 1867.756542] usb 5-2: new low-speed USB device number 24 using ohci-pci
[ 1868.164189] usb 5-2: device not accepting address 24, error -32
[ 1868.300101] usb 5-2: new low-speed USB device number 25 using ohci-pci
[ 1868.707749] usb 5-2: device not accepting address 25, error -32
[ 1868.843660] usb 5-2: new low-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[ 1868.983546] usb 5-2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 1869.634998] usb 5-2: device not accepting address 26, error -32
[ 1869.770899] usb 5-2: new low-speed USB device number 27 using ohci-pci
[ 1870.314436] usb 5-2: device not accepting address 27, error -32
[ 1870.314474] hub 5-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
[ 1876.705297] usb 10-1: new low-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[ 1876.749312] usb 10-1: New USB device found, idVendor=192f, idProduct=0916
[ 1876.749320] usb 10-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 1876.749325] usb 10-1: Product: USB Optical Mouse
[ 1876.749571] usb 10-1: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
[ 1876.763922] input: USB Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0a.0/0000:04:00.0/usb10/10-1/10-1:1.0/input/input21
[ 1876.764180] hid-generic 0003:192F:0916.0006: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [USB Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:04:00.0-1/input0
```

When done, the only things plugged into the USB 3.0 ports are the keyboard and mouse. Help! at the moment the PC is looking like a very high powered doorstop.

Comment: I'm facing this exact issue with my Dell Inspiron running ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Any luck yet?

Comment: It turned out to be a problem on BIOS, my solution is here: ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2276848